# Merge the values of two tables from different SQL Servers

Tags: sql, merge

I have two (linked) sql servers with basically the same setup but they differ in the content. What I want to do is take 2 tables (one from each server) and merge them, so that there are no duplicates ID (e.g., no duplicate `fname`) and that the the `count` are added together

They may look like

```
SERV1.DB1.dbo.Table:
| fname       | count |
----------------------
| 'file1.txt' | 10    |
| 'file2.txt' | 5     |
| 'file3.txt' | 35    |


SERV2.DB2.dbo.Table:
| fname       | count |
----------------------
| 'file1.txt' | 40    |
| 'file2.txt' | 150   |
```

And I want to write a `select` that outputs

```
| fname       | count |
----------------------
| 'file1.txt' | 50    |
| 'file2.txt' | 155   |
| 'file3.txt' | 35    |
```

I don't want a join and a union doesn't merge them the way I want.

**edit**

- It needs to be case-insensitive as the `fname` may (read: will) vary in case
- `fname` has different collations (it's a no problem but worth mentioning)
- I get these two tables by doing a similar `select` on each server. I could create temporary tables but I'd prefer if I didn't have too.

Comment: "I don't want a join" - why not? The simple and obvious thing to do is a full outer join

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever because I thought that a join wouldnt merge my tables the way I wanted them too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easly with a `JOIN`

```
SELECT table1.fname fname, table1.Count + table2.count Count
FROM SERV1.DB1.dbo.Table table1
    FULL OUTER JOIN SERV2.DB2.dbo.Table table2 ON table1.fname=table2.fname
```

**EDIT:** case-sensitive/-insensitive [depends on the column collation](http://mssql.wordpress.com/2007/08/13/case-sensitive-comparisons-or-joins/)

Comment: Thanks, it was a lot easier than I thought haha.

Comment: @user1021726 :D happy to help! look that a left join is needed!

Comment: I'd recommend a full outer join rather than a left, if there are names that appear in table 2 and not in table 1 that should also appear in the results. You'll also need some `COALESCE` love in the `SELECT` clause to ensure you get a name and so that the `+` is protected from `NULL`s.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree with you for the coalesce and not sure about full outer join, it depends on table design. Anyway full outer join will not hurts so i changed my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

This is my own recommendation, based on giammin's answer:

```
SELECT
     COALESCE(t1.fname,t2.fname) fname,
     COALESCE(t1.Count,0) + COALESCE(t2.count,0) Count
FROM
   SERV1.DB1.dbo.Table t1 
    FULL OUTER JOIN
   SERV2.DB2.dbo.Table t2
    ON t1.fname=t2.fname
```

which ensures that all `fname` values from both tables appear in the result, even those that only appear in `SERV2`'s table.